# How to use Python 3.x for simple Portfolio Optimization calcs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think my code below is pretty close, but I'm getting the following error: ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series

Here is my code sample.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader as web
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'api_key_here'

# get the table for daily stock prices and,
# filter the table for selected tickers, columns within a time range
# set paginate to True because Quandl limits tables API to 10,000 rows per call
symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'WMT']
noa = len(symbols)
data = pd.DataFrame()

for sym in symbols:
    data[sym] = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'WMT'], 
                        qopts = { 'columns': ['ticker', 'date', 'adj_close'] }, 
                        date = { 'gte': '2015-12-31', 'lte': '2016-12-31' }, 
                        paginate=True)
data.columns = symbols

(data / data.ix[0] * 100).plot(figsize=(8, 5))
rets = np.log(data / data.shift(1))
rets.mean() * 252
rets.cov() * 252

weights = np.random.random(noa)
weights /= np.sum(weights)
print(weights)
```

I used to pull data from Yahoo finance, and everything worked fine.  Now, after not touching this fro more than a year, I'm playing around with the code, and trying to feed in historical day-end prices, from a non-Yahoo source, and subsequently do my portfolio optimization calculations.  Any thoughts?  As always, thanks.

Comment: Side point: `.ix` access is now depreciated. Use `.loc` or `.iloc` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I just made that update.  I'm not even up to that point yet.  The issue occurs in the loop.  There appears to be some problem with the loop.